# How to rename executable / binary file during runtime using OS package?

Tags: windows, go, filesystems, file-rename

actually this is a pretty straightforward question (with possible tricky implementation maybe). I have a command-line application which executed within a binary file and has an update feature which rename the old file with the newest one.

How can I implement binary file renaming (let's say `exe` in Windows) during runtime of the prior binary using `os` package or other alternatives?

Example : 
prior binary : `version1.exe` 
latest binary : `version2.exe` 
I want `version1.exe` "transform" into `version2.exe` by name, without creating any temporary file or such during runtime.

Comment: "without creating any temporary file or such during runtime" You may want this but I doubt Windows will let you. Just redesign.

Comment: @Volker, in fact, it depends: sometimes, it's possible, sometimes, it's not: I've seen it both ways in the wild. Unfortunately, I do not know the reasons. I wonder if creating a hard link could help in the OP's case: `CreateHardLink{A|W}` is there in `kernel32.dll` since WinXP.

Comment: @Volker  Do you guys have any alternatives approach in golang using intermediary temporary file?